# Blue background on the candidates name when commenting on their own nomination

Tags: feature-request, comments, election, nominations

As there are a lot of comments under every nomination in https://stackoverflow.com/election, it is sometimes difficult to find the answers of the nominee.

It would be handy to have a [blue background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22185/209901) on the comments they write under their own nomination. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, like in [blogs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/?cb=1) the author comments is  in blue and easily diffrentiated

Comment: The names seem to become blue if you click on "Add/show more comments"