# Blue background on Nominee comments only when expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, election

This is similar to [Blue background on the candidates name when commenting on their own nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220521/187954), except it's a bug report, not a feature request.

Currently, the nominee's comments on his/her own post are not highlights, *unless* you click "add / show more comments"

When the page is loaded it looks like:

[image]

AfterI click "add / show more comments", it becomes:

[image]

Could we have the blue highlighting on the post owner's comments there all the time? It becomes difficult to see the nominees responses to questions, especially on nominations where there aren't enough comments to enable the "add / show more comments" features, like Matt's.

Comment: is it fixed now?

Comment: @Ooker: nope. But [SOUP includes a fix](https://github.com/vyznev/soup).

Comment: @MảtijnPieters this report is old, and still no respond to it?

Comment: @Ooker It's finally fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this is done:

[image: blue background on nominee name in comments]

Thanks to Adam Lear for the help here!